# Obtain Boolean values from a Datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, boolean

[image]im getting a DataTable from a (DataTable)DataGridView.DataSource.
This datagridview has two columns whose values are Boolean, displaying like checkboxes.
But when i try to get the values from the dataTable i get a "Invalid Cast Exception" in the Boolean Column. here is my code for getting the values...

```
private void WriteDataGridChanges( int grupoIndex ) {
        if( dataGridView1.RowCount > 0 ) {
            escuela.Grupos[grupoIndex].Alumnos.Clear();
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            foreach( DataRow r in dt.Rows ) {
                /*crear un alumno, usar sus modificadores para los datos acorde con
                 el datagridview y añadirlo al grupo indicado 'lulz'
                 */
                Alumno al = new Alumno();
                al.Nombre = (String)r["Nombre"];
                al.Apellidos = (String)r["Apellidos"];
                al.Cuota = (double)r["Cuota Total"];
                al.CostoMaterial = (double)r["Costo de Materiales"];
                al.MaterialEntregado = (Boolean)r["Material entregado?"];
                al.CuotaCubierta = (Boolean)r["Cuota Cubierta?"];
                al.Parcialidad = (double)r["Parcialidad total"];
                al.ParcialidadMaterial = (double)r["Parcialidad de material total"];
                al.UltimaParcialidad = (DateTime)r["Fecha último pago colegiatura"];
                al.UltimoPagoMaterial = (DateTime)r["Fecha último pago de material"];
                escuela.Grupos[grupoIndex].Alumnos.Add(al);
            }
        }
        edited = false;
    }
```

and here is the code for creating the dataTable and pass it to a dataGridView

```
        private DataTable RefreshGruposGrid( Grupo g ) {
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(String));
        t.Columns.Add("Apellidos", typeof(String));
        t.Columns.Add("Cuota Total", typeof(double));
        t.Columns.Add("Costo de Materiales", typeof(double));
        t.Columns.Add("Material entregado?", typeof(Boolean));
        t.Columns.Add("Cuota Cubierta?", typeof(Boolean));
        t.Columns.Add("Parcialidad total", typeof(double));
        t.Columns.Add("Parcialidad de material total", typeof(double));
        t.Columns.Add("Fecha último pago colegiatura", typeof(DateTime));
        t.Columns.Add("Fecha último pago de material", typeof(DateTime));
        foreach( Alumno a in g.Alumnos ) {
            DataRow r = t.NewRow();
            r["Nombre"] = a.Nombre;
            r["Apellidos"] = a.Apellidos;
            r["Cuota Total"] = a.Cuota;
            r["Costo de Materiales"] = a.CostoMaterial;
            r["Material entregado?"] = a.MaterialEntregado;
            r["Cuota Cubierta?"] = a.CuotaCubierta;
            r["Parcialidad total"] = a.Parcialidad;
            r["Parcialidad de material total"] = a.ParcialidadMaterial;
            r["Fecha último pago colegiatura"] = a.UltimaParcialidad;
            r["Fecha último pago de material"] = a.UltimoPagoMaterial;
            t.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        return t;
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values stored in the Database as `0, 1` or `true false` or `"True" "False"` please clarify

Comment: Also for the DataGridview do you have `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `true` or `false` I am an not mistaken if what you are adding column wise and what you are binding don't match you would need to create `new` columns in for the DataGridView` since you are binding it to a `DataTable`

Comment: hi DJKRAZE im not using a database (it would simplify my life!) because of system requeriments. But i found something interesting right now.

Comment: Will await your updated comments and or amendments to your initial question.. Whether you're using a Database or not you are however still using a DataGridView and Binding it to a Datatable my previous comment about `Auto Generate` may still hold some validity

Comment: sorry i just pressed enter... well AutoGenerateColumns a havent touched that property... also if i run the program but i actullay press the checkbox in the dataGridView it parse correctly, but if i leaved them unchecked then the exception comes

Comment: ok, so in the debugger a have my item array for the DataRow.

Comment: row["myBooleanValue"]={} thats what i see in debug if i dont check the datagridview checkbox

Comment: can you post that portion of the code..? or any other relevant code that deals with this issue..

Comment: sounds like you are missing some logical checks for the checkbox state also is this the actual name `row["myBooleanValue"]`

Comment: no thats no the actual name, that was just and example, i posted a image from what i saw in the debugger, can i add a default value for the datagridview column?

Comment: i see what happend here.. the dault value may be a null if i dont touch anything from the datagridView... if i check twice the checkbox column i actually get the false value and its OK, this happens the same with my DateTime column as i see now, thanks for your replies, i will make a default value for this... THANKS!

Comment: you're welcome. keep in mind that It's always good to `Initialize` values especially when working with `boolean` set initially to it's default value = `false` for Strings `string.Empty` or `object = default(string)` `int`  = to `0` glad I could help point you in the right direction

Comment: yeah thans a lot man, this was very helpful!

Comment: `+1`you're welcome.. glad that you were able to quickly pick up on what I was suggesting to you. sign of a good coder

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the thing was with the default value of the DataGridView, whenever i pressed the checkbox column i get a value, but if i leaved it unchecked it return sort of a null value.